# Why does IPAddress constructor take Int64 instead of UInt32?

Tags: c#, .net

Why does `IPAddress` constructor take `Int64` instead of `UInt32`?  According to Reflector the address is stored as an `Int64` internally (`m_Address`) and the constructor validates it to be within the range valid for `UInt32`.  So I'm just curious why it uses `Int64` and not `UInt32`.

And before anyone says IPv6.. IPv6 is bigger than `Int64` and is stored as an array of `UInt16`.  The `Int64` constructor is only used to generate IPv4 addresses.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Probably because in the [Common Language Specification (CLS)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/12a7a7h3.aspx) of the Common Language Infrastructure (CLI) standard, unsigned types are not required to be supported by a language so they used the smallest signed type that will hold all the possible unsigned values.

> The .NET Framework class library includes types that correspond to the primitive data types that compilers use. Of these types, the following are CLS-compliant: `Byte`, `Int16`, `Int32`, `Int64`, `Single`, `Double`, `Boolean`, `Char`, `Decimal`, `IntPtr`, and `String`.